# Create a repo in Gitlab using CLI

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

We have a `gitlab` setup at our office, and we have somewhat around 100-150 project each week to create over there, while Admin wants to keep the control of creating repos and assigning teams to it, it seems quite a bit of task for anyone to create that many repos every week.

Is there a way to **`create repo on Gitlab using CLI`** - I won't mind if i have to use `ssh` for it.

Comment: [Just push to the repository and it will be automatically created.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66394605/405550)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [gitlab-cli](https://github.com/drewblessing/gitlab-cli) and automate the process using a shell script. I've used this in gitlab 5.x, but according to the site it might not work with gitlab 6.

Comment: gitlab-cli is no longer actively maintained - see author's note: "This may not work with GitLab 6.x+. This project is no longer maintained. For a fully-functional, maintained CLI tool look at http://narkoz.github.io/gitlab/ "

Answer (score 19):

[gitlab-cli](https://github.com/drewblessing/gitlab-cli) is no longer maintained, the author references the [Gitlab](http://narkoz.github.io/gitlab/) module to be used instead - it also includes a CLI tool.

For your specific request - namely creating a project on the command line, use the following command:

`gitlab create_project "YOUR_PROJECT_NAME" "{namespace_id: 'YOUR_NUMERIC_GROUP_ID'}"`

Be sure to use the option `namespace_id` and not `group_id`! If you are not sure what your `GROUP_ID` is, you can use

`gitlab groups | grep YOUR_GROUP_NAME`

to find out.

The parameters for each command can be inferred from the [API documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/gitlab/Gitlab). Any non-scalar valued parameter has to be encoded in an inline YAML syntax (as above).

Comment: To create a public repo, you don't need namespace_id, but visibility_level like this `gitlab create_project "{visibility_level: 10}" $GIT_REPO_NAME`.

Answer (score 16):

Since you just wanted to create a repo, there is no need of third party apps. You can directly send a post request to gitlab API which will create repo.

Go to [account tab](https://gitlab.com/profile/account) in your profile, you will find a private token. Copy that.

Now open terminal and run this command with private token (say `foo`) and your repo name (say `bar`).

```
curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects?private_token=foo -d "{ \"name\": \"bar\" }"
```

For convenience, you can create a shell script, if  you don't want to run this command every time.

```
#!/bin/sh

curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects?private_token=foo -d "{ \"name\": \"$1\" }"
```

Save this to a file `gcr.sh` and make it executable using `chmod +x gcr.sh`.

Now to create a repo name `bar`, run

```
$ ./gcr.sh bar
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this work over gitlab's default http?

Comment: @Gerrat The only thing I get is an 422 HTTP-Error.

Answer (score 7):

In comparison with the prior answers by [ChillarAnand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36150602/) and [eigenfield](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52128349/), although this answer too uses the REST API with `curl`, it also:

1. authorizes against GitLab by providing the token in the header, not in the URL
2. makes `curl` exit with a nonzero code in case of an error (via `-f`)
3. uses the `path` parameter instead of the `name` parameter, thereby avoiding the risk of a dissimilar path from being used

First, [obtain a token](https://gitlab.com/-/profile/personal_access_tokens) with access to the `api` scope.

```
REPO_NAME=foo1
GITLAB_TOKEN=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  # Enter your own.

curl -f -X POST \
  -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${GITLAB_TOKEN}" -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
  "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects" -d "{\"path\": \"${REPO}\", \"visibility\": \"private\"}"
```

This answer is relevant only for creating a repository as a [user](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#create-project). The request for creating a repository as an [admin](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#create-project-for-user) is different.

As an aside, explicitly creating the repo is optional, since GitLab is known to be capable of creating the repo [on first push](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/index.html#create-a-new-project-with-git-push). (*credit: Elan R.*)

Answer (score 6):

Now gitlab support creating new repo just by giving a URL. If your gitlab username is `shahidcodes` then you can just do below steps -

```
git init # init a repo if you don't have already
git remote add origin https://gitlab.com./<your_username>/<new_repo_name>
git push -u origin master
```

You will see below message from git output

```
remote: The private project shahidcodes/new_repo_name was successfully created.
remote:
remote: To configure the remote, run:
remote:   git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/shahidcodes/new_repo_name.git
remote:
remote: To view the project, visit:
remote:   https://gitlab.com/shahidcodes/new_repo_name
remote:
remote:
remote:
To https://gitlab.com/shahidcodes/new_repo_name
 * [new branch]      master -> master
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.
```

By default, GitLab will create a private repo. And there seems no way to configure it to create public.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have in my ~/.bashrc

```
gitlify() {
    [ $# -eq 0 ] && return 1
    repo_name=$1
    username=smeagol
    token=01234567890

    curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects?private_token=$token -d "{\"name\": \"$repo_name\"}"
    if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
        git init
        git add .
        git commit -m "first blood"
        git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:$username/$repo_name.git
        git push -u origin master
    else
        echo "error create gitlab repo $repo_name"
    fi
}
```

You have to first have a token for your username. Once this bash function is in placed, you can use it by:

```
mkdir /tmp/firstblood
echo '#hello world' > /tmp/firstblood/README.md
cd /tmp/firstblood
gitlify fallenangel
```

This snippet is only for gitlab.com. I have another one that I named **gitify** for github.com.

Comment: Since [GitLab 10.5](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/gitlab-basics/create-project.html#push-to-create-a-new-project) you can omit the curl line, as project is created automatically on first push

Comment: Does `curl` really automatically fail with a nonzero exit code if the repo isn't created? I don't believe it does. I'm saying its exitcode is by dfault 0 even if the request fails. That's unless you use `-f`.

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Summary

Easy to use:

- [**lab**](https://zaquestion.github.io/lab/)
- [**gitlab-cli**](https://github.com/makkes/gitlab-cli)

---

### 2. Disclaimer

This answer is relevant for August 2019. In the future, its data may be outdated.

---

### 3. lab (recommended)

#### 3.1. About

lab — CLI tool, making it simple some operations with GitLab repositories. lab is Gitlab equivalent of [**hub**](https://hub.github.com/) extension for GitHub.

#### 3.2. Usage

After first run lab will offer to enter token. [**Create a personal access token**](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html#creating-a-personal-access-token) with desired scope `api` → paste it to terminal → <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Then run [**`lab project create`**](https://zaquestion.github.io/lab/lab_project_create.html):

```
lab project create -n KiraLab --public -d "Kira lab demo project"
```

#### 3.3. Result

- [**Link**](https://web.archive.org/web/20190829093139/https://gitlab.com/Kristinita/KiraLab)

[image: lab]

#### 3.4. Why recommended

Options are available:

1. `--public` — making repository public, not private
2. `-d`, `--description` — creating description

[image: lab description]

---

### 4. gitlab-cli

#### 4.1. About

Cross-platform Go-written command-line utility for GitLab repositories operations.

#### 4.2. Usage

[**Create your GitLab personal access token**](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html#creating-a-personal-access-token) → [**`gitlab-cli login YOUR_TOKEN`**](https://github.com/makkes/gitlab-cli#installation-and-usage) → run [**`gitlab-cli project create`**](https://github.com/makkes/gitlab-cli#commands) command:

```
gitlab-cli project create KiraGitLabCLI
```

#### 4.3. Result

[image: gitlab-cli]

#### 4.4. Note

Please do not confuse this Go project and Ruby [**gitlab-cli**](https://github.com/drewblessing/gitlab-cli) tool from [**@thameera answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19603398/5951529).

---

### 5. External links

1. [**GitLab CLI clients**](https://about.gitlab.com/partners/#cli-clients)
2. [**Instructions, how to create GitHub repository from command line**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/608527/199934) (on Russian)

Answer (score 0):

See `glab` and the command [`glab repo create`](https://glab-cli.io/docs/commands/repo/create)

Quoting the doc:

```
# create a repository under your account using the current directory name
$ glab repo create

# create a repository with a specific name
$ glab repo create my-project
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `export GITLAB_API_TOKEN=______` to your `.bashrc` or relevant file, then run:

```
curl --request POST -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${GITLAB_API_TOKEN}" \
  -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
  "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects" \
  -d "{ \"name\":\"test\", \"description\":\"Description.\" }"
```